# Excel macro to move all subfolders to another location

Tags: excel, vba

I only know to write a macro to copy a file from Folder A to Folder B

```
FileCopy "C:\Documents\Folder A\test.xlsx", "C:\Documents\Folder B\test.xlsx"
```

Could someone help for an Excel macro to MOVE all sub-folders and files under "Folder A" to "Folder B".  Thank you

Comment: Please do some research of your own using google or other search engines and you will find lot of help. Since you are new to SO, I am providing the code as answer.

Comment: @skkakkar.  Thank you for your help.  It's true that as beginner, I might not use the search properly.  I googled but only found the macro to move the whole Folder A into Folder B but not files and folders under Folder A to Folder B.  Hope I can get more familiar to find the answer the already existed. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pl Try This: Change folders as per your requirements.

```
Sub Copy_Folder()
'This example copy all files and subfolders from FromPath to ToPath.
'Note: If ToPath already exist it will overwrite existing files in this folder
'if ToPath not exist it will be made for you.
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim FromPath As String
    Dim ToPath As String

    FromPath = "C:\Process_Contract_Notes"  '<< Change
    ToPath = "C:\Process"    '<< Change


    If Right(FromPath, 1) = "\" Then
        FromPath = Left(FromPath, Len(FromPath) - 1)
    End If

    If Right(ToPath, 1) = "\" Then
        ToPath = Left(ToPath, Len(ToPath) - 1)
    End If

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    If FSO.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
        MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    FSO.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath
    MsgBox "You can find the files and subfolders from " & FromPath & " in " & ToPath

End Sub
```

Comment: Use FSO.MoveFolder to achieve the desired MOVE result.

Comment: @JochenGrahl You are right that as per OP requirement it should be MoveFolder.  I had an apprehension that OP seems to have just joined  SO. In Move method if Destination directory or File exists errors can come up, Though in Copy method these also can come up for existing Directory or Files but severity is less as the original directory and files are intact. If OP is confident and aware of these methods limitations, he can definitely use ~FSO.MoveFolder. I appreciate your highlighting this point.

Comment: Thank you so much skkakkar, It works perfectly to copy all files and subfolders under Folder A to Folder B.  However, when I tried to change FSO.CopyFolder to FSO.MoveFolder as Jochen but it does not work.  Did I miss something?

Comment: @Tan Duong I shall look into it and let you know my findings after a couple of hours as I am away from my computer. In the meanwhile, if program code suggested by me meets your requirement then please accept my answer by ticking below two triangles on the left side of my answer.

Comment: When I tried to change FSO.CopyFolder to FSO.MoveFolder, got error message say "File already exists".  I realize if I delete Folder B, the macro works but it delete the folder A and change to Folder B.  What I need is to move only files and folders under Folder A to an existing Folder B, not to remove the folder A itself.  Appreciate your help

Comment: @skkakkar.  Thank you for your reply.  I just signed up to Stackoverflow yesterday and still try to learn how to use this.  I just click to accept your answer.

Comment: @Tan Duong Thanks. You have rightly clicked. You may please google frequently. You can also search the site by searching Q&A section. Have an enjoyable and rewarding interaction at this site.

Comment: @skkakkar  Thank you, I will continue to search for solution to move the subfolders

Comment: @Tan Duong There are certain inherent limitations in any method. Please go through remarks in the MOVEFOLDER Method link given here and please go through Remarks section. It is too lengthy to reproduce here. It will clarify you everything about this method and its usage features. <https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251326.aspx> I feel bad that I could not respond to you early.